# Mysql - PHP - Checking a users posts and comments likes

Tags: mysql, performance, compare, comments, facebook-like

Would anyone be able to recommend the best way to check if a user has liked a post or comment?

I am currently building a website that has similair features to Facebooks wall.
My website will show a 'wall' of posts from people you follow that you can like or comment on.

For example, comments I have:

- Comments table containing: id, user_id, text (plus other columns)
- Comments Likes table: comment_id, user_id, created

This is the current query I use to get the comments and checks if user has liked it using an inner join on the likes table. It uses an IF() to return **liked** as either **1** or **empty**, which works fine:

```
SELECT comments.id, comments.post_id, comments.user_id, comments.reply_id, comments.created, comments.text, comments.likes, comments.replies, comments.flags, user.name, user.tagline, user.photo_id, user.photo_file, user.public_key,             
            **IF(likes.created IS NULL, '', '1') as 'liked'**
            FROM events_feed_comments AS comments              
            INNER JOIN user AS user ON comments.user_id = user.id
            **LEFT JOIN events_feed_comments_likes AS likes ON comments.id = likes.comment_id AND likes.user_id = :user**                      
            WHERE comments.post_id = :post_id AND comments.reply_id IS NULL                 
            ORDER BY comments.created DESC  
            LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
```

However, I realise that this will not be cacheable for anyone else as it contains the logged in users likes. There may end up being a lot of posts and so will need to introduce caching.

I am wondering what the best way to check the likes will be?

At the moment these are the solutions i can think of:

- I could either select all the comments limited to say 30 at a time (cacheable)
  Then loop over each result doing a fetch/count query in the likes table to see if a user has liked it.
- I could do a fetch from the likes table doing a where in clause using the returned 30 id results.
  Then do some sort of looping to see if the likes value matches the returned results.
- Fetch all of the comments (cacheable), fetch all of a users likes (could be cacheable?), then do some looping / comparing to see if the values match.

I am just not sure what would be the best solution, or if there is some other recommended way to achieve this?

I am thinking the second approach may be best but i'm interested to see what you think?

Updates to show the table Create statements

```
CREATE TABLE `events_feed_comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reply_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `replies` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `flags` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci


CREATE TABLE `events_feed_comments_likes` (
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`,`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci


CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `photo_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(180) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `roles` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`roles`)),
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tagline` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `biography` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `social` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`social`)),
  `specialties` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `available` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `theme` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo_file` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `following` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `followers` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_private` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `public_key` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `show_groups` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `show_feed` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_8D93D64966F9D463` (`public_key`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_8D93D6497E9E4C8C` (`photo_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_8D93D6497E9E4C8C` FOREIGN KEY (`photo_id`) REFERENCES `photos` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we need to see the datatypes, indexes, engines, etc.  Don't worry about "caching" until you have a million users.  Focus on indexing now.

Comment: Thank you Rick. I've updated the question to add the CREATE statements. I definitaly need to add some indexes to the user_id and post_ids

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using If in your SQL query, consider using SQL Case to simplify the query.

```
    CASE --
           WHEN ---- THEN '----'
           
           ELSE '---'
    END
```

Comment: Interesting thank you, I didn't know there was a case statement. Is the benefit just to make the query more simple or is there a performance benefit to this too?

Answer (score 0):

For performance:

```
comments:  INDEX(post_id, reply_id, created)
likes:  INDEX(comment_id, user_id, created)
```

Those improvements *may* eliminate the need for "caching".

Please put "filtering" in `WHERE`, such as `AND  likes.user_id = :user**` and put "relations" in `ON`.  It *can* matter when using `LEFT`, and does help a human reading the query.

If `events_feed_comments_likes` is a many-to-many mapping table, you may want `INDEX(user_id)` also.

I assume this is the query in question:

```
SELECT  comments.id, comments.post_id, comments.user_id, comments.reply_id,
        comments.created, comments.text, comments.likes, comments.replies,
        comments.flags, user.name, user.tagline,
        user.photo_id, user.photo_file, user.public_key,
        IF(likes.created IS NULL, '', '1') as 'liked'
    FROM  events_feed_comments AS comments
    INNER JOIN  user AS user  ON comments.user_id = user.id
    LEFT JOIN  events_feed_comments_likes AS likes  ON comments.id = likes.comment_id
      AND  likes.user_id = :user
    WHERE  comments.post_id = :post_id
      AND  comments.reply_id IS NULL
    ORDER BY  comments.created DESC
    LIMIT  :limit  OFFSET :offset
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Rick. Will that still work moving the likes.user_id to the where as I still need to grab all posts whether they like it or not, that is just for the if statement?

Comment: @JohnMcCaughan - If you are suggesting two different `SELECTs`, please show both ot them (without "**").

Comment: No it's just the one select as above. I'll have a play around and apply the suggestions and see how it goes. Thank you